# Clone APFS Time Machine volume to 2nd hard drive (Big Sur)

Tags: backup, time-machine, disk-utility, big-sur

I run Time Machine on an APFS formatted SSD and wondered, if it is possible to make something like a backup of my backup.

In practice I would like to copy / clone / get an image of my Time Machine SSD to a 2nd external hard drive from time to time, so that I would be able to restore my backup history to another SSD if anything happens to the Time Machine SSD (corrupt backup, ransomware etc.). Is this somehow possible with disk utility or a 3rd party software?

Comment: SuperDuper! used to work fine for cloning pre-APFS Time Machine volumes. An alternative to cloning is to use multiple Time Machine volumes simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly [SuperDuper](https://www.shirt-pocket.com/SuperDuper/SuperDuperDescription.html) as mentioned but there is a way that gives you something like that you have requested.

Set up your external drive as a drive in “System Preferences -> Time Machine.”

When the drive is attached Time Machine will alternate backups between this and your SSD time machine.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible and highly recommended. SuperDuper, as suggested in the comment to your question, will work, and also [Carbon Copy Cloner](https://bombich.com/), which I use.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 You are right. I did not read the question carefully enough and interpreted it as if the OP asked for a second backup method for the original data.

Comment: I do however a backup of my TM backups, flawlessly with CCC. The caveat is that the original backups go to an external drive on the network, so CCC sees a .backupbundle rather than the "raw" Backups.backupdb folders. The CCC backups of the TMbackups end up on a box running Ubuntu server and they are mountable from my macs no issues.